# Initialize variable of a structure - Error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token

Tags: c, variables, struct, compiler-errors, initialization

Here is my structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char apagado;         
    char prop[MAXPLEN];
    char mat[6];
    double valor;
    } veiculo_t;

veiculo_t.apagado='\0';
```

Why can't I initialize the **apagado** variable like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`veiculo_t` isn't a variable. It's a type. You still have to create a variable of that type:

```
veiculo_t veiculo;
veiculo.apagado='\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

`veiculo_t` is a type not a variable.

You use the type to declare a variable.

```
veiculo_t myvar = { '\0' } ;
```

Or

```
myvar.apagado='\0';
```